# php explode elements in an array

Tags: php, arrays, explode

how could I explode each elements in an array?

```
Array
(
    [0] => countryId:2, productId:1, status:1, pId:18, xId:pdgje5566
)
```

please see below for above array:

```
$searchfor = $xId;

header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$contents = file_get_contents($file);
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";

// search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){

   print_r($matches[0]);
   //echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);

}
```

please advise, thanks.

Comment: Is each element in the array a string or is that JSON representation for a 2d array there? Also what do you want to split on?

Comment: @Sammaye data are get from text file

Answer (score 8):

```
foreach ($array as &$value) {
  $arr = array();
  foreach (explode(', ', $value) as $el) {
     $ret = explode(':', $el);
     $arr[$ret[0]] = $ret[1];
  }
  $value = $arr;
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation and is promoting the notion that dumping a snippet is enough effort to earn unicorn points.

Comment: @mickmackusa Yep, but this answer is answered at the dawn of time of stackoverflow, someone is just to want to get a runnable code snippet. And for such question itself, the code is just enough for the educational purpose :)

Comment: Yes,  I realize that I am poking an old post. The "dawn of time" came 3/4 years earlier for Stack Overflow.  Old code-only answers inspire new users to believe that new code-only answers are acceptable and gather unicorn points.  By role modeling better posting practices, we encourage future improvement in the culture of posting with the intent to educate/empower not just the OP but thousands of researchers.  I often use ancient pages to close new duplicates -- I can only do so in good faith when the old page is educational enough to resolve the new page.

Comment: It might just be easier to find another page that is demonstrating how to explode a string on two different delimiters and close this page as a duplicate of that one.  There will be many to choose from.

Comment: @mickmackusa Nice point 